# jQuery tabs: Get rid of 'previous' navigation button on second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm using the following code for some jQuery tabs. To navigate between each of the three tabs, there are previous and next buttons. On the first tab, the 'previous' button is hidden, on the third tab, the 'next' button is hidden- this is fine. I need to remove the 'previous' button on the second tab if possible.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
Tab 1
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
Tab 2
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
Tab 3
</div>
</div>

<div class="Footer">
<div class="divleft">
    <button id="btnMoveLeftTab"  type="button" value="Previous Tab"    
text="Previous Tab">Previous Tab
    </button>
</div>
<div class="divright">
    <button id="btnMoveRightTab" type="button" value="Next Tab"  text="Next   
Tab">Next Tab
    </button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Clearboth"></div>
```

The script used for the tabs:

```
  $(function () { 
//Get the first tab in document and will assume will always use first one
var selectedTab = $(document).find('div[class^="ui-tabs"]').first();

//Navigation button, select tab when button click.
$(".Footer").on('click', ':button', function () {
    var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
    if (this.id == "btnMoveLeftTab") {
        if (selected >= 1) {
            selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected - 1);
        }
    } else {
        selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected + 1);
    }
});

//Tab activated, only display next on first tab, and previous in last tab
selectedTab.tabs({

    activate: function (event, ui) { 
        var active = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
        var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");

        if (active == 0) {
            $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
        }else if 
        (selectedTab.find("li:not(li[style='display:none'])").size()-1 == selected){
            $("#btnMoveRightTab").hide();
        }else{
            $("#btnMoveLeftTab").show();
            $("#btnMoveRightTab").show();
        }

    }
});

//First time loading hide the previous button
$("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
});
```

I've tried changing $("#btnMoveLeftTab").show();  to  $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide(); but this means I lose the 'previous' button under my third tab, which I need to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as your `activate` function should help.

```
activate: function (event, ui) { 
    var active = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
    var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");

    switch(active) {
        case 0:
        case 1: $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
                $("#btnMoveRightTab").show();
                break;
        case 2: $("#btnMoveLeftTab").show();
                $("#btnMoveRightTab").hide();
                break;
    }
}
```

Runnable code snippet:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
      var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
      $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

    }
  }

);

$(function() {
  //Get the first tab in document and will assume will always use first one
  var selectedTab = $(document).find('div[class^="ui-tabs"]').first();

  //Navigation button, select tab when button click.
  $(".Footer").on('click', ':button', function() {
    var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
    if (this.id == "btnMoveLeftTab") {
      if (selected >= 1) {
        selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected - 1);
      }
    } else {
      selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected + 1);
    }
  });

  //Tab activated, only display next on first tab, and previous in last tab
  selectedTab.tabs({

    activate: function(event, ui) {
      var active = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
      var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");

      switch (active) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
          $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
          $("#btnMoveRightTab").show();
          break;
        case 2:
          $("#btnMoveLeftTab").show();
          $("#btnMoveRightTab").hide();
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  //First time loading hide the previous button
  $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eef;
}
#tabs {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/* Note that jQuery UI CSS is loaded from Google's CDN in the "Add Resources" pane to the left.  Normally this would be done in your <head> */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    Tab 3
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>

<div class="Footer">
  <div class="divleft">
    <button id="btnMoveLeftTab" type="button" value="Previous Tab" text="Previous Tab">Previous Tab
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="divright">
    <button id="btnMoveRightTab" type="button" value="Next Tab" text="Next   
Tab">Next Tab
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Clearboth"></div>
```